# How to make Gui for control center

Tags: ros, ros2, communication, ros-melodic, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm trying to learn ROS. I'm totally noob. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and ROS Melodic Morenia.

My question is I'm trying to create a robot that can control from control center. Robot system is running with ROS i know that but can't figure out how will my computer communicate with the system. I saw some web gui s but i am curious about what if i want to communicate locally i mean maybe with usb to usb or with ethernet cable like host-client. How can i do that and which packages can help me in ROS.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354082/how-to-make-gui-for-control-center/) by [Morgenstern](https://answers.ros.org/users/55396/morgenstern/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-06-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Morgenstern,

As I see this, you have two problems:

1. **Set a communication between machines**. Since ROS is a middleware it provides a full set of characteristics and functionalities that will allow you to stablish a communication between machines. While one of your machines runs the ROS Master you will be able to configure a communication between this machine and another one running ROS (in the same network).You can check this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) for more info about it. As for your question about local communication, you do not need to focus too much on that, since when you run your ROS master in your machine you will be able to communicate locally with it as the node uses the local IP of the machine that is running the master by default. Yo can learn more about this [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Concepts) and [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup).
2. **Generate a control GUI able to send commands to your other machine**. There are several ways to do this, I will post here my approach and I am sure other members of this forum will be glad of posting other ones. To generate a GUI for ROS I generally prefer the [QT enviroment](https://www.qt.io/), it is a great and easy tool to generate decent GUI with less effort. It will force you to learn how Qt works but I think it is a great way of doing what you want. You can check a ROS QT project [here](http://wiki.ros.org/qt_ros).

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2